# Iterating through python numpy array when used with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to iterate through the elements in a numpy array so I can treat any zero elements separately. The code below works for straighforward evaluations, but not when used with scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). Is there a way to make this work with the curve_fit fn?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def my_fn(x_array, b, a):
    y = []
    for x in np.nditer(x_array): #This doesn't work with curve_fit()
        if x == 0:
            y.append(0)
        else:
            y.append(b*(1/np.tanh(x/a) - a/x))
    return np.array(y)


x_meas = [0, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 600]
y_meas = [0, 0.275, 1.22, 1.64, 1.77, 1.84, 1.9]
xfit = np.linspace(0,600,601)
yfit2 = my_fn(xfit, 1.95, 8.2) #manual fit

#Not working
#popt, pcov = curve_fit(my_fn, x_meas, y_meas, p0=[1.95, 8.2]) 
#yfit1 = my_fn(xfit, *popt) #auto fit

figure(1)
plot(x_meas, y_meas, 'o', xfit, yfit2)
show()
```

Comment: Please do always specify what "it doesn't work" means.  What's the error message you get when you use this with `curve_fit()`?  Please provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the [larsmans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533837/279627) actually work, you will also need to convert your data samples to NumPy arrays:

```
x_meas = numpy.array([0, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 600], float)
y_meas = numpy.array([0, 0.275, 1.22, 1.64, 1.77, 1.84, 1.9], float)
```

(Converting `y_meas` is not strictly necessary.)

Here is larsmans' code with my suggestions incorporated:

```
def my_fn(x, b, a):
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    nonzero = x != 0
    x = x[nonzero]
    y[nonzero] = b*(1/np.tanh(x/a) - a/x)
    return y
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works. Actually, by just changing x_meas and y_meas to numpy array types allows my original my_func() to work. This code should be faster though. One point - it's probably better to use y = np.zeros_like(x, float) because the default data type for zeros_like is int64.

Comment: @user602117: The default for `zeros_like()` isn't `int64`, but rather the same datatype as the parameter.  If the parameter is a Python list, the list will first be converted to a NumPy array using the usual rules.  If this list happens to contain only `int` values, an integer data type is used.  That's why I added `dtype` parameters in the definitions of `x_meas` and `y_meas`.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to iterate through the elements in a numpy array so I can treat any zero elements separately.

No you don't; this should be a lot faster and work everywhere:

```
def my_fn(x, b, a):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    nonzero = np.where(x != 0)
    x = x[nonzero]
    y[nonzero] = b*(1/np.tanh(x/a) - a/x)
    return y
```

Comment: The code will be faster if you drop the call to `np.where()` and simply use `nonzero = x != 0`.  Moreover, `y = np.zeros_like(x)` would always give `y` the correct data type, even if `x` consists of, say, complex numbers.